# rake wont create XML file

Tags: ruby, file-io, nokogiri, builder

I'm a bit lost here as to why my `rake` task will not create the desired XML file, however it works fine when I have the method `build_xml` in an `.rb` file.

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'nokogiri'  
require 'open-uri'  

namespace :xml do
  desc "xml build test"
  task :xml_build => :environment do
    build_xml
  end 
end

def build_xml
  # build xml docoument
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.root {
      xml.location {
        xml.value "test" 
      }
    }
  end
  File.open("test.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(builder.to_xml) }
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "wont"? What's the error or result that you aren't expecting?

Comment: the script seems to work fine, the xml is shown on the screen and trace shows up no error.  however the test.xml file is not created as per File.open("test.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(builder.to_xml) }

Answer (score 1):

When I execute your rakefile with `rake xml:xml_build`, I get an error that the task `environment` is not defined. If I remove `environment` as a dependency of `xml_build` and then run it again it works fine and creates the xml file.

So my guess is that your environment task causes an error and xml_build never runs (or the task doesn't exist in your real rakefile either, so just remove it as a dependency).

Comment: Indeed, he's probably copied this Rakefile code from a rails project (where `environment` would be defined for you) but isn't running it inside one now.

Comment: Also, not a big deal but `open-uri` isn't needed for this script :)

Comment: i have removed the environment dependency, script output xml to screen ok but the test.xml is still not created.

Comment: could it be some file permission issue when running the script as a rake task?

again the same script successfully created the test.xml file when i had the code snippet in the .rb file

Comment: ok, i have worked out the problem. the File.open("test.xml", 'w') was not working, i had to include the full path to test.xml.
my rake environment is probably not setup probably.